Weak* compactness of subset of $L^q$
Let $\mathcal{Z}=L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and its dual space $\mathcal{Z}^*=L^q(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$. Let
$$\langle Z, Z^*\rangle = \int Z \, Z^* d\mu$$
be their dual paar.
EDIT: Let $c:\mathcal{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.END EDIT
I want to show that a subset of the dual space, given by
$$\{Z^*\in\mathcal{Z}^*:\langle Z, Z^*\rangle \leq c(Z) \, \forall Z\in\mathcal{Z}\}$$ is weak* compact.
I think I somehow have to use the theorem by Banach-Anaoglu:
Let $\mathcal{Z}$ be a banach space. The closed unit ball $\{Z^*\in\mathcal{Z}^*:\|Z^*\|_*\leq 1\}$ is compact in the weak* topology.
But I cant get there. First I dont know how I can extend Anaoglus theorem to the case of bounded sets whose bound is great than 1. Moreover I dont know how to express the dual pair in terms of the $L^q$ norm. And lastly I am not sure if I have to also show that this set is closed (and how I would do that).

The set ${Z^* \in \mathcal Z^: \langle Z, Z^\rangle \le c; \forall Z \in \mathcal Z}$ equals ${0}$, isn't it? If $Z^* \ne 0$, then there is $Z \in \mathcal Z$ such that $ \langle Z, Z^\rangle \ne 0$. Then by multiplying $Z$ by an appropriate constant $\alpha$ you can make $\langle \alpha Z, Z^\rangle \ge c$.

Do you maybe want the set to be $${Z^\in\mathcal{Z}^:\langle Z,Z^*\rangle\leq c\text{ for all }Z\in\mathcal{Z}\text{ with }\lVert Z\rVert=1}$$or something similar?

@Matsmir sorry i cannot follow your argument: yes we may be able to multiply with a constant but the condition is that $\langle Z, Z*\rangle$ be smaller or equal than c and not $\langle \alpha Z, Z*\rangle$

You're asking that $\langle Z,Z^\rangle\leq c$ for all $Z$, so if $\langle Z_1,Z^\rangle\neq0$ then we can choose $\alpha$ appropriately so that, taking $Z_2=\alpha Z_1$, $\langle Z_2,Z^\rangle>c$. Since $\mathcal{Z}$ is a vector space, $Z_2\in\mathcal{Z}$, so this would contradict that we must have $\langle Z_2,Z^\rangle\leq c$

Thanks for your explanation! Would things change if $c$ was a function of $Z$? So we have a different real valued $c$ for every $Z$?

@Matsmir I edited my question. Could you give me an answer for it?

In case $c$ is bounded itself, in the sense that $c(Z) \leq C\|Z\|$ for some constant $C > 0$ independent of $Z$, this is true. The proof is essentially the same as the proof of Banach-Alaoglu: the main observation is that there is also a lower bound on $\langle Z, Z^\ast \rangle$, since,
$$\langle Z, Z^\ast \rangle = -\langle -Z, Z^\ast \rangle \geq -c(-Z)$$
So for any $Z^\ast$ in your subset, $\langle Z, Z^\ast \rangle \in [-c(-Z), c(Z)]$. Thus, your subset embeds into,
$$\prod_{Z \in \mathcal{Z}} [-c(-Z), c(Z)]$$
which is compact per Tychonoff’s theorem. The set of linear functionals $Z^\ast$ with $\langle Z, Z^\ast \rangle \leq c(Z)$ for all $Z$ is closed since it corresponds exactly to those elements of $\prod_{Z \in \mathcal{Z}} [-c(-Z), c(Z)]$ which are linear, i.e., your subset corresponds to,
$$\{f \in \prod_{Z \in \mathcal{Z}} [-c(-Z), c(Z)]: f(aZ) = af(Z) \; \forall Z \in \mathcal{Z}, a \in \mathbb{C}, f(Z_1 + Z_2) = f(Z_1) + f(Z_2) \; \forall Z_1, Z_2 \in \mathcal{Z}\}$$
which is clearly closed in $\prod_{Z \in \mathcal{Z}} [-c(-Z), c(Z)]$, whence compact. The final thing to note is that the linear functionals $Z^\ast$ with $\langle Z, Z^\ast \rangle \leq c(Z)$ for all $Z$ are automatically bounded. Indeed,
$$-C\|Z\| = -C\|-Z\| \leq -c(-Z) \leq \langle Z, Z^\ast \rangle \leq c(Z) \leq C\|Z\|$$
So $|\langle Z, Z^\ast \rangle| \leq C\|Z\|$ and $Z^\ast$ is bounded.
I’m not sure about the general case. The issue here is that, in general, $Z^\ast$ with $\langle Z, Z^\ast \rangle \leq c(Z)$ for all $Z$ need not be bounded, so the “correct” compact set defined above can contain unbounded linear functionals. If some of these unbounded linear functionals can be approximated pointwise by bounded linear functionals in the compact set, then the collection when restricted to bounded linear functionals will be no longer compact. As such, I would assume the result is false in that case, but I haven’t been able to come up with a counterexample yet.

Thank you for your answer and efforts! So in my case the function $c$ is not bounded. So I know that this result holds in my question I am just wondering how to show it...

@guest1 Hmm, I don’t believe the result is true for general $c$, though I haven’t found an explicit counterexample. But perhaps you can share some additional information on the $c$ in your situation?

So what I dont understand is why it embedds to this cartesian product of intervals. Is this somehow related to product topology?

@guest1 This Cartesian product is equipped with the product topology, yes. The embedding simply sends $Z^\ast$ to itself, as a function from $\mathcal{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. (I’d suggest working through a proof of Banach-Alaoglu theorem if you find this confusing. What I wrote in the answer is really nothing more than copying the proof of Banach-Alaoglu.)
